# How to I change a website url which I use for advertising affiliate products?

Tags: affiliate, commission-junction

I have a website which I am using as a affiliate marketing. Now due to a change in strategy I need to change the domain of the website. So My question is do I have to re subscribe to all the merchants/stores or I can just use a 301 redirect from my old website to the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you have to change in the apache settings or nginx settings or the server you are using ,This will redirect all the requests coming to your old website to your new website.

Comment: Does this means that I don't need to re apply to affiliate programs.

Comment: yes...if they are not hardcoded values. but you may have to check if they are counting other urls as other agents.